# FactoryGirl: how to combine together 2 traits setting the same association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

The following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do    
  factory :program do
    trait :successful do
      status :success
      logs { build_list :program_log, 2, :success }
    end

    trait :uninstalled do
      successful
      logs { build_list :program_log, 1, :uninstall }
    end
  end
end
```

provides 2 traits. The `uninstalled` trait includes the `successful` trait, but the `logs` association is overridden when I use it. Is it possible to create a trait that will just append new logs to the mixed-in trait. In the case above, I would like to have the `uninstall` trait with 3 logs - 2 of success and 1 of uninstall

Comment: have you looked into the `after(:build)` syntax?  It seems like you could `after(:build)` do something like `logs << build_list :whatever_log, 1 :inst`?  There's a nice example of how it could be used here... http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/useful-factory-girl-methods/

Answer (score 1):

You can't, if you use the `logs` syntax. You need to use a [`callback`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks)

```
FactoryGirl.define do    
  factory :program do
    trait :successful do
      status :success
      after(:build) do |object|
         object.logs.concat build_list(:program_log, 2, :success)
      end
    end

    trait :uninstalled do
      successful
      after(:build) do |object|
         object.logs.concat build_list(:program_log, 1, : uninstall)
      end
    end
  end
end
```